# Scheme error when programming point-distance formula - attempt to apply non-procedure

Tags: scheme, formula, distance, point

I am attempting to program the point distance formula using Scheme. I am very close to getting it, except I am getting an error.

The exact error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "In [54]", line 5, col 11, in 'application'

File "In [54]", line 5, col 11

RunTimeError: attempt to apply non-procedure '4'
```

Here is my code:

```
; code for the distance procedure

(define (distance p1 p2) (sqrt (+ (* (- (car(p2)) (car(p1))) (- (car(p2)) (car(p1)))) (* (- (car(cdr(p2))) (car(cdr(p1)))) (- (car(cdr(p2))) (car(cdr(p1))))))))

(distance (4 5) (3 2))
```

For reference, the point distance formula is:

√((x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2)

Comment: Follow scheme syntax consistently. A general structure for a function in scheme is `(function arg1 arg2 ...)`, so you can have something like `(car p1)` instead of `(car (p1))` etc.

Comment: `(4 5)` attempts to pass the argument `5` to the procedure `4`. Review the basics of Scheme syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is generally better to format Scheme code correctly instead of putting everything in just one line.

And it is useful to name intermediate values. If your formula contains `x1`, `x2`, `y1` and `y2`, create Scheme variables with those names. This makes it easier to understand the solution.

Scheme hast several abbreviations for nested `car` and `cdr` functions. If you need the `car` of a `cdr`, you can use `cadr`.

Scheme allows you to use mathematic symbols in variable names. If a variable contains the difference of `x2` and `x1`, you can name it `x2-x1`. This enhances the readability of Scheme's Polish notation.

```
(define (distance p1 p2)
  (let ((x1 (car p1))
        (y1 (cadr p1))
        (x2 (car p2))
        (y2 (cadr p2)))
    (let ((x2-x1 (- x2 x1))
          (y2-y1 (- y2 y1)))
      (sqrt (+ (* x2-x1 x2-x1)
               (* y2-y1 y2-y1))))))
```

If you want to pass list literals to functions, you have to quote them in order to prevent evaluation.

```
(distance '(4 5) '(3 2))
```

Or use evaluation correctly:

```
(distance (list 4 5) (list 3 2))
```